# C++ compilation problem showing problem with header files on macos

Tags: c++, macos

tried to run a cpp file and i get the same error no matter which file I run . How to fix this ?
This is the same even if I use g++ (homebrew) .
I thought about deleting usr/include/c++/v1 and then try to re-install it . But not confident if that would be a good idea  ,

```
$ clang++ contrc.cpp
In file included from contrc.cpp:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:37:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:214:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iosfwd:95:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/wchar.h:137:77: error: use of undeclared identifier 'wcschr'
wchar_t* __libcpp_wcschr(const wchar_t* __s, wchar_t __c) {return (wchar_t*)wcschr(__s, __c);}
                                                                            ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/wchar.h:144:87: error: use of undeclared identifier 'wcspbrk'
wchar_t* __libcpp_wcspbrk(const wchar_t* __s1, const wchar_t* __s2) {return (wchar_t*)wcspbrk(__s1, __s2);}
                                                                                      ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/wchar.h:151:78: error: use of undeclared identifier 'wcsrchr'; did you mean 'wcschr'?
wchar_t* __libcpp_wcsrchr(const wchar_t* __s, wchar_t __c) {return (wchar_t*)wcsrchr(__s, __c);}
                                                                             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/wchar.h:139:16: note: 'wcschr' declared here
const wchar_t* wcschr(const wchar_t* __s, wchar_t __c) {return __libcpp_wcschr(__s, __c);}
               ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/wchar.h:158:86: error: use of undeclared identifier 'wcsstr'; did you mean 'wcschr'?
wchar_t* __libcpp_wcsstr(const wchar_t* __s1, const wchar_t* __s2) {return (wchar_t*)wcsstr(__s1, __s2);}
                                                                                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/wchar.h:141:16: note: 'wcschr' declared here
      wchar_t* wcschr(      wchar_t* __s, wchar_t __c) {return __libcpp_wcschr(__s, __c);}
               ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/wchar.h:158:86: error: no matching function for call to 'wcschr'
wchar_t* __libcpp_wcsstr(const wchar_t* __s1, const wchar_t* __s2) {return (wchar_t*)wcsstr(__s1, __s2);}
                                                                                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/wchar.h:141:16: note: candidate disabled: <no message provided>
      wchar_t* wcschr(      wchar_t* __s, wchar_t __c) {return __libcpp_wcschr(__s, __c);}
               ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/wchar.h:158:93: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'wchar_t *' with an lvalue of type 'const wchar_t *'
wchar_t* __libcpp_wcsstr(const wchar_t* __s1, const wchar_t* __s2) {return (wchar_t*)wcsstr(__s1, __s2);}
                                                                                            ^~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/wchar.h:141:38: note: passing argument to parameter '__s' here
      wchar_t* wcschr(      wchar_t* __s, wchar_t __c) {return __libcpp_wcschr(__s, __c);}
                                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/wchar.h:165:60: error: unknown type name 'size_t'
wchar_t* __libcpp_wmemchr(const wchar_t* __s, wchar_t __c, size_t __n) {return (wchar_t*)wmemchr(__s, __c, __n);}
                                                           ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/wchar.h:167:57: error: unknown type name 'size_t'
const wchar_t* wmemchr(const wchar_t* __s, wchar_t __c, size_t __n) {return __libcpp_wmemchr(__s, __c, __n);}
                                                        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/wchar.h:169:57: error: unknown type name 'size_t'
      wchar_t* wmemchr(      wchar_t* __s, wchar_t __c, size_t __n) {return __libcpp_wmemchr(__s, __c, __n);}
                                                        ^
In file included from contrc.cpp:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:37:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:214:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iosfwd:189:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'mbstate_t'
typedef fpos<mbstate_t>    streampos;
             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iosfwd:190:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'mbstate_t'
typedef fpos<mbstate_t>    wstreampos;
             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iosfwd:192:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'mbstate_t'
typedef fpos<mbstate_t>    u8streampos;
             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iosfwd:195:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'mbstate_t'
typedef fpos<mbstate_t>    u16streampos;
             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iosfwd:196:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'mbstate_t'
typedef fpos<mbstate_t>    u32streampos;
             ^
In file included from contrc.cpp:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:37:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:215:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:14:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:506:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string_view:175:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/__string:57:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:639:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/initializer_list:46:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstddef:49:9: error: no member named 'ptrdiff_t' in the global namespace
using ::ptrdiff_t;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstddef:50:9: error: no member named 'size_t' in the global namespace
using ::size_t;
      ~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstddef:53:9: error: no member named 'max_align_t' in the global namespace
using ::max_align_t;
      ~~^
In file included from contrc.cpp:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream:37:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:215:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:14:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string:506:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string_view:175:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/__string:57:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:639:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/initializer_list:61:5: error: unknown type name 'size_t'
    size_t    __size_;
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/initializer_list:65:38: error: unknown type name 'size_t'
    initializer_list(const _Ep* __b, size_t __s) _NOEXCEPT
                                     ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This seems unrelated to xcode but your code in general. Anyway please always post a [mre]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.